# SQL calculate new column based on other queries with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building up a large SQL query to calculate everything in one go based on a table. I need a column called `total_revenue`, which should be the sum of `total_commission` and `total_profit` together.

Right now, I'm constructing a new inner join to do this, but this inner join that calculates `total_revenue` is an overhead.

How can I, instead, run a inner join on the result of my upper query to then do a sum of `total_commission` + `total_profit` without doing another inner join on another table, here's my current SQL:

```sql
SELECT

    # Affilaite
    Conversion.aff_id,

    # Revenue
    JoinedRevenue.total_revenue,
    
    # Commission
    JoinedCommission.total_commission,

    # Profit
    JoinedProfit.total_profit
    
FROM
    tlp_conversions AS Conversion
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Commission.aff_id,
        Commission.created,
        SUM(Commission.amount) AS total_commission
    FROM
        tlp_commissions AS Commission
    WHERE
        Commission.created >= '2022-10-03 00:00:00'
        AND
        Commission.created <= '2022-10-03 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY
        Commission.aff_id
) AS JoinedCommission
  ON JoinedCommission.aff_id = Conversion.aff_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Application.tlp_aff_id,
        ApplicationResponse.application_id,
        ApplicationResponse.result,
        Commission.seller_code,
        Commission.application_response_id,
        Commission.created,
        SUM(Commission.amount) AS total_profit
    FROM
        tlp_commissions AS Commission
    INNER JOIN tlp_application_responses AS ApplicationResponse
        ON ApplicationResponse.id = Commission.application_response_id
    INNER JOIN tlp_applications AS Application
        ON Application.id = ApplicationResponse.application_id
    WHERE
        Commission.created >= '2022-10-03 00:00:00'
        AND
        Commission.created <= '2022-10-03 23:59:59'
        AND
        ApplicationResponse.result = 'Accepted'
        AND
        Commission.seller_code = 44
    GROUP BY
        Application.tlp_aff_id
) AS JoinedProfit
  ON JoinedProfit.tlp_aff_id = Conversion.aff_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Application.tlp_aff_id,
        ApplicationResponse.application_id,
        Commission.application_response_id,
        Commission.created,
        SUM(Commission.amount) AS total_revenue
    FROM
        tlp_commissions AS Commission
    INNER JOIN tlp_application_responses AS ApplicationResponse
        ON ApplicationResponse.id = Commission.application_response_id
    INNER JOIN tlp_applications AS Application
        ON Application.id = ApplicationResponse.application_id
    WHERE
        Commission.created >= '2022-10-03 00:00:00'
        AND
        Commission.created <= '2022-10-03 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY
        Application.tlp_aff_id
) AS JoinedRevenue
  ON JoinedRevenue.tlp_aff_id = Conversion.aff_id
WHERE
    Conversion.conversion_time >= '2022-10-03 00:00:00'
    AND
    Conversion.conversion_time <= '2022-10-03 23:59:59'
    AND
    Conversion.aff_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Conversion.aff_id
```

I was hoping I could just do another SQL join that loops over each returned result in my query and appends `total_revenue` based on the row column of each?

```sql
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(JoinedProfit.total_profit + JoinedCommission.total_commission) AS total_revenue
) AS JoinedRevenue
```

But this isn't the right syntax here.

[image]

Comment: Which version of MySQL / MariaDB do you use? Please [edit] your question. It matters because MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2+ offer [common table expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/). These can make it easier to write complex queries.

Comment: Is there any point in selecting many columns, grouping by only 1 then joining on only 1? Especially since the main query only selects aggregated values,

Comment: Which is why I've opened this Stack Overflow question, to ask for some help.